# Build the python environment with VSCode, and when I installed the python plug-in, VSCode couldn't recognize the 'python: Select Interpreter' command

Tags: visual-studio-code

After installing Anaconda3
Build the python environment with VSCode, and when I installed the python plug-in, VSCode couldn't recognize the 'python: Select Interpreter' command
VSCode prompts "No Commands matching"

Try reinstalling the plugin, but it still won't work. I checked the VSCode documentation and found no method

Does anybody have this problem? How to solve it